# Should I check implementation details or use class public API only in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Consider the following example:

```
public class Foo {

    protected List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    void add(int i) { arr.add(i); }

    int size() { return 0; }
}

public class FooTest {

    Foo foo = new Foo();

    @Test
    void checkAdd() {
        foo.add(1);
        assertEquals(1, foo.size()); // fail
        assertEquals(1, foo.arr.size()); // pass
    }
}
```

Sorry, I have a lame question but still unable to find an answer. Is it considered as a bad practice to check implementation details as a part unit testing? Obviously testing one part of public API via another part of public API may (and most likely will) lead to incorrect results. On the other side implementation can be very complicated, just imagine if you want to test HashMap.

Comment: Highly opinionated question. There are good arguments for most sides. And the truth is likely somewhere in the middle. https://beust.com/weblog/2005/07/18/testing-private-methods-you-bet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no immediate connection between size() and arr.size(), what if you wanted to test that there is another list that adds elements with a condition?

I think you should have another test that checks if the size() returns the same result as the arr.size() if this is the expected behaviour.
After this test, you can proceed with the assumption that size() always will return the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

You should check the public methods. Also you don't need to check the implementation details instead test each of the methods by their input and output.